# making a wordpress slider display portrait and landscape image

Tags: wordpress, slider, landscape, portrait

Ok so i have to tell that i am not an expert in coding or stuff like that.

Here is the problem that i have found. I did a website for a friend of mine and i have noticed that on the homepage the incorporated slider would not show images in portrait but it would crop them in landscape. Is it possible to make the slider display the portrait images in portrait without cropping them?

This is the website and i am talking about the slider in the first page. www.saveriogenise.com

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the slider you are using, the slider you are using now is using a custom image size (550x335px), i think you can change the settings in the theme or slider admin, if not you have to edit the theme codes chose different size or re-size image keeping aspect ratio etc ...